# Nodejs - update user password from a boostrap form with ajax

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to let the user update their password without reloading the page but I keep getting `POST /user?userid=something 404` error. Can anyone spot what I did wrong? Thanks.

Bootstrap modal

```
       <form method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">New password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" onkeyup='checkPassword();' required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm new password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Re-enter your password" onkeyup='checkPassword();' required>
                        <span id='message'></span>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

ajax script

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#submit').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var new_password = $('#password').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/user',
            type: 'post',
            data: new_password,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

index.js - server side

```
router.post('/user'), function (req, res) {
    User.updateOne({ '_id' :  req.query.userid }, {$set: {password: createHash(req.body.password)} });
}
```

Comment: Did you try `method: 'POST'` instead of `type:..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesnt work its because you dont have `method : 'POST'` also  the data you send is not an Object its a value. If you want to use `req.body.password` you should send it as `{password:"thepassword"}`

Also pass user id in the data since its not a `GET`.

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            userid: "theUserId",
            password: $('#password').val()
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/user',
            method : 'POST'
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and in the route you have to send back a status ok.

```
//you should use body-parser middleware for this

router.post('/user', function (req, res) {
    User.updateOne({ '_id' :  req.body.userid }, {$set: {password: createHash(req.body.password)} });
    //you have to inform the client what happened!
    res.status(200).send();
}
```

Comment: The error is `POST /user?userid=5aabfe24be446d0b1cc821d2 404 5.770 ms - 1380`, my url before sending the post request is `http://localhost:3000/user?userid=5aabfe24be446d0b1cc821d2`

Comment: @TriNguyen How do you send the request? I mean the `?userid` all I see its just `/user` in ajax. Can you try changing  `url: '/user',` to        `url: 'http://localhost:3000/user',`

Comment: Yeah I tried. I even put `console.log(req.body)` in the route. It doesn't print out anything. Does that mean the data actually has not reached the server?

Comment: you get `404` witch means that you haven't register the route. Have you done `app.use(route)`?

Comment: I have `var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport);
app.use('/', routes);` as part of the passport. I also put the post method of user in passport function which is exported

Comment: Anyway, if I have not registered the route, the get methods for user would not work too but it works for user and any other pages.

Comment: Updated my answer check the route part. You never send anything back to the client. eg 200 ok or 500 error

Comment: Found it, it was a typo. I had `router.post('/user'), function (req, res, next) {` instead of `router.post('/user', function (req, res, next) {`.